# Bean validation which is disabled in JSF is re-enabled after submit

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jsf-2, bean-validation

Given: JSF2 Form with some input fields, including password field.

Main Goal: If the password field is left empty (resulting in `password.isEmpty()==true` or `password==null`), the validation and password binding should be skipped!

No-Go: Separate DTO (i know it would be more clean, but i am not allowed to decide this)

view.xhtml:

```
<h:form id="someForm">
    <h:outputLabel value="Password " />
    <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{myBackingBean.entity.password}" immediate="true" redisplay="false" required="false">
        <f:validateBean disabled="true"/>
        <f:validator validatorId="myPasswordValidator"/>
    </h:inputSecret>
    <p:message for="password" />
    <p:commandButton value="Save" update="someForm">
        <f:actionListener binding="#{myBackingBean.updateEntityAction()}" />
    </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

MyPasswordValidator.java:

```
@FacesValidator(value = "myPasswordValidator")
public class MyPasswordValidator implements Validator {
@Override
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
    Object value) throws ValidatorException {
            String password = (String) value;
if (password == null || password.isEmpty()) {
    UIInput inputComponent = ((UIInput) component);
        inputComponent.setValid(true);
        inputComponent.setRequired(false);
}
return;
    }
}
```

MyBackingBean.java:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "myBackingBean")
@ViewScoped
public class MyBackingBean extends GenericBackingBean<....> {

    public ActionListener updateEntityAction(){
    return new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void processAction(ActionEvent event)
          throws AbortProcessingException {
          // .... hybernate stuff
        }
      };
  }
}
```

Entity.java:

```
  class Entity{

  @NotNull
  private String password;
  // ...
  public void setPassword(String password)  {
        // do nothing if null
        if(password == null || password.isEmpty()){

              log.warn("Password not changed for some reason ....");
          return;
        }
        // set and crypt password ...
  }
```

This actually works, but only for the first submit, each submit after the first results in a error message (no exception ... probably it gets eaten somewhere  ... ?). What is interesting, is that the message says "kann nicht null sein'" (german), and i have actually no clue who or what is producing this message.

What i conclude, is that after the first submit the default bean validation is activated again.

Any Idea?

Comment: The  "kann nicht null sein" indeed sounds like Hibernate Validation. 
Usually, when this validation is done by JSF, the field holding the value is added as a prefix.

Comment: The message "darf nicht null sein" comes from `ValidationMessages_de.properties`, you find that one within the JAR `hibernate-validator-<version>.jar` under `/org.hibernate.validator`. So you seem right, somewhere the validator strikes back. When rendering this messages via JSF, some message bundle holds `javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.MESSAGE = {1} {0}` so that the message is like: `"password" darf nicht null sein.` Either in your project this got changed (look for the key in your message properties) or the validation is possibly started from somewhere else (persisting?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a non-hack solution to this problem!

Instead of writing:

```
<h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{myBackingBean.entity.password}" immediate="true" redisplay="false" required="false">
    <f:validateBean disabled="true"/>
    <f:validator validatorId="myPasswordValidator"/>
</h:inputSecret>
```

I had to write:

```
<f:validateBean disabled="true">
<h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{myBackingBean.entity.password}" immediate="true" redisplay="false" required="false">
    <f:validator validatorId="myPasswordValidator"/>
</h:inputSecret>
</f:validateBean>
```

The First variant does not survive post-requests!

Thanks anyway for the hints and regards!

Answer (score 2):

This message is coming from JSR303 bean validation annotation `@NotNull`. JSR303 bean validation is by default *also* executed during JPA `EntityManager#persist()` and `update()`.

Like as that you can disable JSR303 bean validation in JSF by `<f:validateBean disabled="true">`, you can disable JSR303 bean validation in JPA by the following entry in `persistence.xml`:

```
<validation-mode>none</validation-mode>
```

Keep in mind that this affects **all** JSR303 bean validation annotations. You might want to remove the `@NotNull` and make use of a conditional `required="true"`.

#### See also:

- [Hibernate documentation - Chapter 4.1.2](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/additionalmodules.html#d0e3900)

Answer (score 1):

The message "darf nicht null sein" comes from `ValidationMessages_de.properties`, you find that one within the JAR `hibernate-validator-<version>.jar/org/hibernate/validator`.

So you seem right, somewhere the validator strikes back. When rendering this messages via JSF, some message bundle holds

```
javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.MESSAGE = {1} {0}
```

so that the message is like: "password" darf nicht null sein. Either in your project this got changed (look for the key in your message properties) or the validation is possibly started from somewhere else (Hibernate persisting?).